# How can I JUnit test a model within Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-activity

Below I have an example of a model I have created within Android Studio to be utilised within my application.

Could someone with experience in this area, offer me examples of unit tests I could carry out on this model (in android) to get me started?

**- I'm referring to JUnit Testing via Google Android Testing**

Creating functions to JUnit test utilising(extending) TestCases (`junit.framework`) etc

code for **Contact** model:

```
public class Contact extends MainModel
{
    private Long id;
    private String personName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String occupation;



    public Long getId() 
    { 
        return id; 
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    { 
        this.id = id; 
    }



    public String getPersonName() 
    { 
        return personName; 
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) 
    { 
        this.personName = personName; 
    }



    public String getPhoneNumber()
    { 
        return phoneNumber; 
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) 
    { 
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber; 
    }



    public String getOccupation()
    {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation)
    {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

}
```

Comment: For getting started with testing you'll want to take a look at the official testing documentation, then move onto roboelectric and robotium from there. As for tests, we don't know the constraints on your fields. For example, you could test whether the `Long id` is a positive number throughout the application. You should really start with the docs though, it's a LOT of information to take in.

Comment: I understand your point, but all I'm asking for is some examples to get me started using the context of a model within Android as above.

Comment: That's why I recommended http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html

Comment: Why would you test a model class? As long as the class is a simple dto, I don't see any reason for testing it, you put a property into it and you get it. That is all.

Comment: Andy Res - Could you offer any examples for doing that within Android,thanks

Comment: I just said that testing model classes is not necessary. You don't get much value out of it.

Comment: I understand your point, but it's something I'm wanting to discover how to do in the context of above

Comment: I see, well, in this case I believe you should follow the advice of @G_V, by taking a look at the official testing documentation.

Comment: some tests in android/robo  proj.  https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/third_party/gif_decoder/src/androidTest/java/com/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/GifHeaderParserTest.java  model would just be any POJO class' tests. u can find them ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Been looking into similar junit tests in Android lately, this should defiantly get you started. It should explain how to test the getting and setting

```
public class SurveyTest extends TestCase {

private Survey survey;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();  
    survey = new Survey();
}

public void testSurvey() {
    survey.toString();
}

public void testSurveyLongString() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testGetId() {
    long expected = (long) Math.random();
    survey.setId(expected);
    long actual = survey.getId();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

public void testGetTitle() {
    String expected = "surveytitle";
    survey.setTitle(expected);
    String actual = survey.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);  
}

public void testIsActive() {
    Boolean expected = true;
    survey.setActive(expected);
    Boolean actual = survey.isActive();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

public void testGetQuestions() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable way that I've found to write unit tests for classes that don't depend on the Android libraries (Activities, Context, etc.) is to install Robolectric.

Then, since Robolectric is based on JUnit, in addition to Robolectric tests, which do typically involve Context and friends, you have the infrastructure in place to support simple, non-Android JUnit tests.

Comment: Can't you create functions to test whether certain data can be accepted utilising(extending) TestCases. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?